# Fulltext search over all git repositories (gitlab)

Tags: gitlab, full-text-search

Is there a way to search over all git repositories with gitlab?

At the moment we are using the open source version of gitlab.

Since it is open source, there should be a way to enable it without switching to the commercial version....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search over "all Git repositories" must first determine its scope: all branches or only the master branch.

Because a search across *all* branches is not easy to implement, and is discussed in this [2 years old issue 1086](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/1086).

Searching across all repositories was also recently requested ([issue 9794](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/9794)), but also not implemented yet.

A [GraphQL query](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/) *might* come close of what you are looking for, but its API is still alpha, and might be limited to one project or group.

Comment: For me "only the master branch" would be enough.

Comment: @guettli I agree. But I don't see that feature implemented yet.

Comment: Off topic, but related: Some time ago owncloud was forked to nextcloud because the management tried to slow down the development of useful features in the open source version. The owncloud managers wanted people to pay for features. AFAIK nextcloud is very successful today.